# How to convert lscpu output to JSON format with no trailing spaces?

Tags: bash, jq

I tried to convert it to the JSON format by `-J` flag, but older `lscpu` versions have no such functionality.
The solutions I've found here didn't help me.

I want to put out here the solution I got from member of another community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About solution from [@palmasd1](https://superuser.com/users/1851220/palmasd1)

```bash
LANG=C
lscpu | 
sed -r 's/$ //g;s/ [ ]+//g' | 
awk -F ':' 'BEGIN{printf"{\"cpu\":["}{print x"{\""$1"\":\""$2"\"}";x=","}END{printf"]}"}' | 
tr -d '\n'
```

Explanations:

- `LANG=C`: translation deactivation
- `lscpu`: the command
- `awk -F ';' ...`: use `:` character as input field separator

```
   BEGIN {
       printf "{\"cpu\":["
   }
   {
       print x "{\""$1"\":\""$2"\"}"
       x=","
   }
   END {
       printf "]}"
   }
```

- - `BEGIN { ... }`: executed before all line treatments
  - `{ ... }`: treatment for each line

    - `x` variable is used for adding a coma before each line except first where `x` is empty
    - `$1` and `$2` contains first and second field values
  - `END { ... }`: executed after all line treatments
- `tr -d '\n'`: remove all LINE FEED character (new line under *UNIX* systems)

Personal notes about this script:

1. It's not really the same format than `lscpu -J` command
2. The output format is not protect against JSON special characters (like `/`, `"`...) and field value who contains `:` character

Answer (score -1):

```
LANG=C

lscpu   |   sed -r 's/$ //g;s/ [ ]+//g'  | 
awk -F ':' 'BEGIN{printf"{\"cpu\":["}{print x"{\""$1"\":\""$2"\"}";x=","}END{printf"]}"}'  | 
tr -d '\n'
```

Explanation

1. Output of `lscpu` is fed to `sed` which strips out all spaces at the front of a line, and all double spaces are replaced by single spaces.
2. `awk` reformats each line into JSON by wrapping the label and the data in double quotes.  Also wraps each line in curly braces, and prefixes every line except the first with a comma.
3. Finally, `tr` deletes all the new lines, making one single line of output.

This can be "pretty printed" by piping the output to `jq`

Comment: Can you give some explanation? That "awk" script is not easy readable.

Comment: @Dominique I'm sorry, I cannot because that one line solution I got by member of another community. It works, and author doesn't mind against it'd posted here. So I leave it here for anybody who will experiencing the same problem.